# How can I get data from form input array value by key in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have input array like,

```
<input type="text" name="cost[1]" value="10">
<input type="text" name="cost[21]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="cost[46]" value="332">
<input type="text" name="cost[55]" value="32">
```

Let me know, node js code to get value by key

Comment: Please post the best code you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you using express or a similar node js backend?

Comment: I am trying to get value like: req.body.cost[55], but getting undefine, I am using express

Comment: Does this answer your question? [form element array keys in node and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197408/form-element-array-keys-in-node-and-express)

Comment: Thanks, it's working